# WinAPI Creating another window after destroying previous one

Tags: c++, winapi, getmessage

I know how to create child windows. But what if I want to create one window (for example to customise settings) and after destroying it - a second one (based on a [HGE](http://hge.relishgames.com/) engine). If I could break message loop by WM_DESTROY I could create second window after this message loop. But as I know [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns 0 only in WM_QUIT message and I cannot send this message because it means: "Close the application" not "Close the window". So my question is: How can i break message loop when first window gets WM_DESTROY? Is that actually possible?

Comment: Create a dialog window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#modeless_box

Comment: Thanks, dialog window was the best solution :) .

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple really, and you should not be attempting to break out of you message loop.

- When you handle the WM_CLOSE message for the first window, call CreateWindow etc. to create and show the second window.
- When you handle the WM_DESTROY message for the second window, call PostQuitMessage to bring things to a close.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PostMessage.

```
#define WM_USER_CREATE_NEW_CHILD WM_USER + 1
void OnDestroy() // on destroy first child
{
PostMessage( parentWindow, WM_USER_CREATE_NEW_CHILD, 0, 0 );
```